# Laravel Media system vs simple S3 storage link

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm tasked to finish an ElasticBeanstalk Backend that's written in Laravel.
I don't know any PHP, nor have I any experience in Laravel.

I have a simple Model "Beer", that has a Stock Photo associated with it.
I found out that Laravel has a Media system which could be used for that, where you can add Media to Models and retrieve it that way.

But could I just save the stock photo to an S3 instance, and save the path to it on the model/ in the database? Then, on retrieval, access the S3 file, and send a public url to the client?

That sounds easier to me because I don't need to understand this media system. Are there any disadvantages to doing it this way? The Stock photos are <1MB, and each beer has only one.

Comment: So you would manually add the image to S3, then manually associate it with model? Is this a one-time thing or does someone else need to manage this?

Comment: I'd probably automate this for future maintenance. But with the Laravel Media system, wouldn't this be the same issue? Someone would have to connect the file to the media on the model, no?

Comment: Yes, someone needs to associated the image with the model, but then "magic happens" as far as persistence. In the S3 version, someone needs S3 credentials and an S3 interface first, then the add an image, set correct settings and get a URL. Then they use another set of credentials and an interface and associate. If you managers of this are comfortable with this complexity, it might be okay, but the "magic happens" is where developers come into the equation.